# Splitting a html line to obtain an output

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a html file for 3 pieces of information (Country, long and lat). I am able to find the correct line however splitting it is being a pain. I can do it if the information doesn't change or remains one world however it doesn't.
Here is my code

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=81.55.99.47')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.readlines()
```

This returns the html page, I will be replacing the hardcoded 'IP=81.55.99.47' with a file of IP later, so the country may change

Here is the code I started with, which works but it doesn't work if the IP is, say United States based.

```
country = the_page[173]
lineof_country=country.split()
result=lineof_country[5]
con=result.split('<')
print con[0]
```

Here is an example of line 173 that would not work:

```
<td align="left" class="arial_bold"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/united states" target="_blank"> United States</a> <img src='/flags/us.gif' alt="united states" align="absmiddle" ></td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @PruthviRaj, please be careful with your edits... I have reviewed a large number of them today and it *appears* to me as though you are just trying to earn some reputation with them, rather than *actually* trying to help. Adding a `Python-2` tag to a question already marked with `Python` and one that does *not* mention `Python-2` anywhere in it is somewhat dubious. Remember that moderators can see *all* of your edits.

Comment: @Sheridan So amn't i helping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
>( *[^>]+ *)</a>
```

The complete commands:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = re.search('> *([^>]+) *</a>', country)
>>> print x.group(1)
France
```

A second example:

```
>>> country2 = '<td align="left" class="arial_bold"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/united states" target="_blank"> United States</a> <img src="/flags/us.gif" alt="united states" align="absmiddle" ></td>'
>>> import re
>>> x = re.search('> *([^>]+) *</a>', country2)
>>> print x.group(1)
United States
```

This approach also removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
(?<=>)([\w ]+)(?=</a>)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/uQ0iL0

Python:

```
import re

str='<td align="left" class="arial_bold"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/united states" target="_blank"> United States</a> <img src='/flags/us.gif' alt="united states" align="absmiddle" ></td>'

str=re.match("(?<=>)([\w ]+)(?=</a>)",str)
print str.group()
```

Output:

```
 United States
```

Note: I'm not totally familiar with python syntax, so please forgive me if the above code is not exactly correct, but you get the idea..  And the regex example works.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need, however when I run in python 2.7 I'm getting the error: AttribueError: 'NoneType object has no attribute 'group'.
I may just being an idiot, thanks!

Comment: @Ziconius, Try `str.group(0)`, or maybe `str.group(1)`.  I'm sorry, I'm not to familiar with python, but one of those should do it.